# string[] and string to DataGridView-Datasource

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview, datasource

i have collection of class "Microsoft.Exchange.Management.TransportLogSearchTasks.MessageTrackingEvent"
this is microsoft class.

this class build like the following class

```
public class  MTE 
    {
        private DateTime timestamp;
        private string clientIp;
        private string clientHostname;
        private string serverIp;
        private string serverHostname;
        private string sourceContext;
        private string connectorId;
        private string source;
        private string eventId;
        private string internalMessageId;
        private string messageId;
        private string[] recipients;
        private string[] recipientStatus;
        private int? totalBytes;
        private int recipientCount;
        private string relatedRecipientAddress;
        private string[] reference;
        private string messageSubject;
        private string sender;
        private string returnPath;
        private string messageInfo;

        private new DateTime Timestamp
        {
            get { return timestamp; }
            set { timestamp = value; }
        }

        public new string ClientIp
        {
            get { return clientIp; }
            set { clientIp = value; }
        }

        public new string ClientHostname
        {
            get { return clientHostname; }
            set { clientHostname = value; }
        }

        public new string ServerIp
        {
            get { return serverIp; }
            set { serverIp = value; }
        }
        public new string ServerHostname
        {
            get { return serverHostname; }
            set { serverHostname = value; }
        }
        public new string SourceContext
        {
            get { return sourceContext; }
            set { sourceContext = value; }
        }
        public new string ConnectorId
        {
            get { return connectorId; }
            set { connectorId = value; }
        }
        public new string Source
        {
            get { return source; }
            set { source = value; }
        }
        public new string EventId
        {
            get { return eventId; }
            set { eventId = value; }
        }
        public new string InternalMessageId
        {
            get { return internalMessageId; }
            set { internalMessageId = value; }
        }
        public new string MessageId
        {
            get { return messageId; }
            set { messageId = value; }
        }
        public new string[] Recipients
        {
            get { return recipients; }
            set { recipients = value; }
        }
        public new string RecipientStatus
        {
            get { return[] recipientStatus; }
            set { recipientStatus = value; }
        }
        public new int? TotalBytes
        {
            get { return totalBytes; }
            set { totalBytes = value; }
        }
        public new int RecipientCount
        {
            get { return recipientCount; }
            set { recipientCount = value; }
        }
        public new string RelatedRecipientAddress
        {
            get { return relatedRecipientAddress; }
            set { relatedRecipientAddress = value; }
        }
        public new string Reference
        {
            get { return[] reference; }
            set { reference = value; }
        }
        public new string MessageSubject
        {
            get { return messageSubject; }
            set { messageSubject = value; }
        }
        public new string Sender
        {
            get { return sender; }
            set { sender = value; }
        }
        public new string ReturnPath
        {
            get { return returnPath; }
            set { returnPath = value; }
        }
        public new string MessageInfo
        {
            get { return messageInfo; }
            set { messageInfo = value; }
        }

}
```

When i am doing

```
Collection<MTE> newMTE = new Collection<MTE>();
datagridview1.datasource= newMTE;
datagrid1.datasource = newMTE
```

on DGV i can see at all the string[] properties
on the datagrid i can see them but as property type and not as a value
image example:

http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5519/10725217114_226ddd96c7_m.jpg

my collection have millions of rows, so i need an easy to process solution.

thank you all for the help

Answer (score 0):

newMTE is a collection itself and your `string[]` are collection of items too (string array).
You can use something like Grouping or Show Row Details to show subrows of a row.

Examples here:
http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

Comment: Do You have a winform solution (not a wpf solution).